# Reorder levels of MultiIndex in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(num,letter,color) 
                    for num in range(1,3) 
                    for letter in ['a','b','c'] for color in ['Red','Green']], 
                    names=['Number','Letter','Color']))
>>> df['Value'] = np.random.randint(1,100,len(df))
>>> df
                     Value
Number Letter Color       
1      a      Red       97
              Green     61
       b      Red       97
              Green     98
       c      Red       91
              Green     47
2      a      Red       17
              Green     63
       b      Red       26
              Green     73
       c      Red       34
              Green     68
```

But I actually want my index to be ordered 'Letter, Color, Number'.

I currently do this as follows:

```
>>> df.reset_index().set_index(['Letter','Color','Number'])
                     Value
Letter Color Number       
a      Red   1          97
       Green 1          61
b      Red   1          97
       Green 1          98
c      Red   1          91
       Green 1          47
a      Red   2          17
       Green 2          63
b      Red   2          26
       Green 2          73
c      Red   2          34
       Green 2          68
```

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's better to use [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) to manipulate the order of MultiIndex levels. Just pass in a list of the level names/numbers in the order you want:

```
>>> df.reorder_levels(['Letter','Color','Number'])
                     Value
Letter Color Number       
a      Red   1          41
       Green 1          56
b      Red   1          43
       Green 1          42
c      Red   1          89
       Green 1          18
a      Red   2          55
       Green 2          93
b      Red   2          64
       Green 2           9
c      Red   2          21
       Green 2          93
```

There's also [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) if you simply want to swap the positions of two levels.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in place?

Comment: @BallpointBen Added an answer that does -- you can call `reorder_levels` directly on the Index.

Answer (score 3):

## Inplace Modification

Call [**`MultiIndex.reorder_levels`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels.html?highlight=reorder_levels#pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels), then assign the new index to your DataFrame.

```
df.index = df.index.reorder_levels(['Letter', 'Color', 'Number']) 
df

                     Value
Letter Color Number       
a      Red   1          41
       Green 1          56
b      Red   1          43
       Green 1          42
c      Red   1          89
       Green 1          18
a      Red   2          55
       Green 2          93
b      Red   2          64
       Green 2           9
c      Red   2          21
       Green 2          93
```

Since Index objects are immutable, you cannot get over creating a new Index, but you can avoid duplicating your data by otherwise calling `df.reorder_levels`.