# Reshape Multilevel Index and Column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe

```
multicol = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['1','1','2','2','2'],
           ['A','B','A','B','C']], names=('Num','Base'))
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,1,2,3,4],[3,2,1,2,3],
     [4,3,2,1,2],[5,4,3,2,1]], index=multicol, columns=multicol)
```

[image]

I want to reshape it to be like this

```
| Num | Base | Base | Value |
+-----+------+------+-------+
|(1,1)|   A  |   A  |   1   |
+-----+------+------+-------+
|(1,1)|   A  |   B  |   2   |
+-----+------+------+-------+
|(1,1)|   B  |   A  |   2   |
+-----+------+------+-------+
|(1,1)|   B  |   B  |   1   |
+-----+------+------+-------+
|(1,2)|   A  |   A  |   3   |
+-----+------+------+-------+
    .....................

    .....................
|(2,2)|   C  |   C  |   1   |
+-----+------+------+-------+
```

I have tried to use `stack()`, but the new order is `Num | Base | Base | Num | value |`. How to achieve a new dataframe with a result likes the one I expected?

Thank you.

Comment: kindly share the source data, not pics. just a couple of rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder levels of MultiIndex in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029608/reorder-levels-of-multiindex-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Yes and No. I need the row is ordered by index too, but I found function `sort_index()` and now I got what I want. Thanks :)