# How do I change the order of my rows in my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if there is a way to rearrange the order of rows in my data frame the following way.
Currently, my multi-index data frame looks like this:
[current order of rows in data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQi9O.png)

However, I would like to change the order to this:
[preferred order of rows in data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jUef.png)

Is there any way how I could change the order efficiently so it is applied to the entire dat frame?

Comment: `df.sort_values(['gameId', 'playId', 'nflId', 'frameId'])` should be all you need. Maybe with an `inplace=True`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder levels of MultiIndex in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029608/reorder-levels-of-multiindex-in-a-pandas-dataframe)